# Cisco IP Phone Trying To Use Javascript XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest, voip, cisco

I am trying to write a web broswer where I can get my Cisco 7942 phone to dial. I am using firefox to not deal with the same origin/domain issues. I am not using a webserver, just the browser page accessing the phone directly.

I keep getting a NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Failure

I am able to access(just access...not send any XML objects) the phone if I manually type the URL `http://172.25.11.59/CGI/Execute` in my browser page...so I don't know.

```
document.domain = "company.com";

    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xml.open("post", "http://172.25.11.59/CGI/Execute", false);
            xml.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic MTgyMjg6MTgyMjg=");
            xml.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

            xml.send('<CiscoIPPhoneExecute><ExecuteItem URL="Dial:2102263232" /></CiscoIPPhoneExecute>');

        console.log(xml.status);
        console.log(xml.responseText);
        console.log("it ran")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it is the Cisco phone that is denying me still.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml.send is missing 'XML='

`'XML=<CiscoIPPhoneExecute><ExecuteItem URL="Dial:2102263232" /></CiscoIPPhoneExecute>'`

and are you sure that your authorization server returns 'AUTHORIZED'?